# UPS specifications

Tags: current, ups

In a UPS specication, in Input data section, it says current consumption is 18.6A maximum? What is the meaning of this? I am using a DC power supply before this in my circuit. Is it that the size of (current rating) the DC power supply more that this value (i.e. 18.6?)?

Answer (score 1):

> Input data section ... 18.6A maximum ... What is the meaning of this?

Pretty much exactly what it says.  The maximum input current this UPS will draw is 18.6 A.  That tells you, for example, that it needs at least a 20 A circuit.  If you power it from a 15 A circuit, it might pop the breaker occasionally.

A typical unspecified "UPS" means a device that takes normal line power in, and provides normal line power out.  The special thing it does is to provide the line power out for a while after the input line power goes away.  It can do this because it stores energy internally in a battery.

If you are supplying DC to your UPS, then you are either doing something wrong, or this isn't a normal line-power UPS, and you need to provide more specs for your unit.